# how to avoid circular import when defining annotated relationship in sqlalchemy2.0

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

Below is an example used in the official doc:

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent_table"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    child: Mapped["Child"] = relationship(back_populates="parent")


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child_table"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    parent_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("parent_table.id"))
    parent: Mapped["Parent"] = relationship(back_populates="child")
```

This two classes should be separated in two files, but I have to import the Parent class in the Child file, and import Child class in the Parent file as I have this `Mapped["Parent"]` and `Mapped["Child"]`. Then I have no idea to fix the circular error.

It would be ok if defined like this:

```py
child = relationship("Child", uselist=False, back_populates="parent")

parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="child")
```

We do not need to import the class in each file using string. And that's what I am doing in the project

But I wonder how to make the annotation things work

ref: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one